# Foreign Key explaination

Tags: mysql

ChatBox Table - ID(FK),RoomID(FK),UserID(FK),Text,created_at

Rooms Table - ID(PK), Name

Users Table - ID (PK), Name, Handle

How to query the database to display

created_at, Text, and Handle for a specific RoomID. ?

For example
When I do

SELECT `created_at`,`TextA`,`UserID` FROM `ChatBox` WHERE `RoomID` = 1 ORDER BY `ID`;

I get created_at, TextA and UserID but I dont Know how can I switch the 
column UserID with the corresponding Handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out,

SELECT created_at, TextA, userHandle FROM ChatBox INNER JOIN Users ON ChatBox.UserID = Users.userID WHERE RoomID = 1;

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for JOIN. Try this

```
 SELECT c.created_at, c.TextA, c.UserID, u.Handle
   FROM ChatBox c
   JOIN Users u ON c.UserID = u.ID
```

The `JOIN` operation is what makes relational datababse management systems deserve the name *relational.* You'd be wise to study it and learn to use it.

Comment: Is this based on the value of RoomID?

Comment: How can I test this on phpmyadmin to confirm the query also?